# TCL:Variable value is not updated after clicking checkbutton

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to set up a sequence of checkbuttons, when clicked these will set the variable value linked to these buttons as 1.
Run button will only run the checks for which checkbutton is selected.
The global variable value eg: check_H1 is not updated when button is clicked.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/wish

package require Tk

frame .top -width 50 -height 30 -borderwidth 5 -padx 5 -pady 5 -relief raised
checkbutton .top.c1 -text H1 -variable "check_H1" -command {set_h1}
checkbutton .top.c2 -text H2 -variable "check_H2" -command {set_h2} 
checkbutton .top.c3 -text H3 -variable "check_H3" -command {set_h3}
checkbutton .top.c4 -text H4 -variable "check_H4" -command {set_h4}
checkbutton .top.c5 -text H5 -variable "check_H5" -command {set_h5}
checkbutton .top.c6 -text H6 -variable "check_H6" -command {set_h6}

button .top.b1 -text "RUN" -command [list select $check_H1 $check_H2 $check_H3 $check_H4 $check_H5 $check_H6] 
grid .top
grid .top.c1 -row 2 -column 2 
grid .top.c2 -row 2 -column 3 
grid .top.c3 -row 3 -column 2 
grid .top.c4 -row 3 -column 3 
grid .top.c5 -row 4 -column 2 
grid .top.c6 -row 4 -column 3 
grid .top.b1 -row 5 -column 5

proc select {check_H1 check_H2 check_H3 check_H4 check_H5 check_H6} {
    #upvar check_H1 check_H2 check_H3 sa3 check_H4 sa4 check_H5 sa5 check_H6 sa6
    puts "Value of H1 is $check_H1\n"
    puts $check_H2
    puts $check_H3
    puts $check_H4
    puts $check_H5
    puts $check_H6

    if {$check_H1 == 1} {
        run_h1
    }
    if {$check_H2 ==1} {
        run_h2
    }
    if {$check_H3 ==1} {
        run_h3
    }
    if {$check_H4 ==1} {
        run_h4
    }
    if {$check_H5 ==1} {
        run_h5
    }
    if {$check_H6 ==1} {
        run_h6
    }
}

proc set_h1 {} {
    global check_H1
    set check_H1 1
    puts $check_H1
    puts "H1 is set\n"
}
proc set_h2 {} {
    global check_H2
    set check_H2 1
    puts "H2 is set\n"
}
proc set_h3 {} {
    global check_H3
    set check_H3 1
    puts "H3 is set\n"
}
proc set_h4 {} {
    set check_H4 1
    puts "H4 is set\n"
}
proc set_h5 {} {
    set check_H5 1
    puts "H5 is set\n"
}
proc set_h6 {} {
    set check_H6 1
    puts "H6 is set\n"
}

proc run_h1 {} {
    global check_H1 
    puts "this loop is for H1\n"
}
proc run_h2 {} {
    global check_H2
    puts "this loop is for H2\n"
}
```

Comment: The apparent value of each variable as seen by select is fixed to the value of the variable at the time the button . top.b1 was created.

Comment: Also, you don't need to write a callback to set the value of the checkbutton variable. The variable will be updated to reflect the state of the button. (Unless you meant to do what it does: make the button impossible to unselect.  It's better to disable the button in that case.)

Comment: Why are all the various `set_`* procedures different?

Comment: @Danish, because you were using the `list` command to contain the call to the select proc, all the variable would have been substituted **when that button command was executed**. As Jerry demonstrates, just call select with no args, and declare all the variables as global inside the select proc.

Answer (score 2):

When running the script, it feels a lot of things don't work as I think it was intended to. I changed a few things, and removed the variables from the button command since the variables are passed to the command to be run at the start rather than at the point the button is pressed.

I have also removed all the `set check_HX 1` because they force the checkbutton to a single state. That said, I didn't touch any other functionality.

```
package require Tk

frame .top -width 50 -height 30 -borderwidth 5 -padx 5 -pady 5 -relief raised
checkbutton .top.c1 -text H1 -variable "check_H1" -command {set_h1}
checkbutton .top.c2 -text H2 -variable "check_H2" -command {set_h2} 
checkbutton .top.c3 -text H3 -variable "check_H3" -command {set_h3}
checkbutton .top.c4 -text H4 -variable "check_H4" -command {set_h4}
checkbutton .top.c5 -text H5 -variable "check_H5" -command {set_h5}
checkbutton .top.c6 -text H6 -variable "check_H6" -command {set_h6}

button .top.b1 -text "RUN" -command select
grid .top
grid .top.c1 -row 2 -column 2 
grid .top.c2 -row 2 -column 3 
grid .top.c3 -row 3 -column 2 
grid .top.c4 -row 3 -column 3 
grid .top.c5 -row 4 -column 2 
grid .top.c6 -row 4 -column 3 
grid .top.b1 -row 5 -column 5

proc select {} {
  global check_H1 check_H2 check_H3 check_H4 check_H5 check_H6
  puts "Value of H1 is $check_H1"
  puts "Value of H2 is $check_H2"
  puts "Value of H3 is $check_H3"
  puts "Value of H4 is $check_H4"
  puts "Value of H5 is $check_H5"
  puts "Value of H6 is $check_H6"
  if {$check_H1 == 1} {run_h1}
  if {$check_H2 == 1} {run_h2}
  if {$check_H3 == 1} {run_h3}
  if {$check_H4 == 1} {run_h4}
  if {$check_H5 == 1} {run_h5}
  if {$check_H6 == 1} {run_h6}
}

proc set_h1 {} {
  global check_H1
  puts "H1 is set to $check_H1"
}

proc set_h2 {} {
  global check_H2
  puts "H2 is set to $check_H2"
}

proc set_h3 {} {
  global check_H3
  puts "H3 is set to $check_H3"
}

proc set_h4 {} {
  global check_H4
  puts "H4 is set to $check_H4"
}

proc set_h5 {} {
  global check_H5
  puts "H5 is set to $check_H5"
}

proc set_h6 {} {
  global check_H6
  puts "H6 is set to $check_H6"
}

proc run_h1 {} {
  global check_H1 
  puts "This loop is for H1 $check_H1"
}

proc run_h2 {} {
  global check_H2
  puts "this loop is for H2 $check_H2"
}

proc run_h3 {} {
  global check_H3
  puts "this loop is for H3 $check_H3"
}

proc run_h4 {} {
  global check_H4
  puts "this loop is for H4 $check_H4"
}

proc run_h5 {} {
  global check_H5
  puts "this loop is for H5 $check_H5"
}

proc run_h6 {} {
  global check_H6
  puts "this loop is for H6 $check_H6"
}
```

Comment: It appears the main change was to the RUN button and the select proc, yes?

Comment: Yes, thanks Jerry and Glenn, i realized lately that list is not required anymore and with few changes i was able to run, i  understand i don't need so may set_ proc, but then can i drop the -command option of checkbuttons, if yes then i don't need those so may set_* procs , i can only query on variable

Comment: @glennjackman yes, those and the interfering `set` in the procs.

Comment: @DanishSheikh that's right, you don't need the proc to set the variables. The checkbuttons are designed to change the value of their variable as you click on them.